# What is the proper replacement for x == undefined?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm trying to cleanup some code (fix [jshint](http://www.jshint.com/) warnings).

What's the best replacement for

```
if (x == undefined) {...}
```

?

I'm using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), is the following equivalent:

```
if (x === null || _.isUndefined(x)) {...}
```

Or am I missing some edge cases?
What is equal (`==`) to undefined? (assuming nobody did `var undefined = 'asdf'` or anything evil like that).

Comment: `if (typeof x === 'undefined')`

Comment: Why do you want to replace this?

Comment: @xbonez why typeof? why not `x === undefined`?

Comment: @H2CO3 "fix jshint warnings" in post

Comment: @Kos: Because `undefined` is not a keyword

Comment: @Bergi - undefined is definitely a language construct: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

Comment: @xbonez - the code I'm replacing was `x == undefined`. If `x` is null, this check passes. I don't want to change the behavior of the code, just make it more specific / pass jshint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `x == undefined` you actually check for two values of `x` - `undefined` itself and `null`. Take note, though, that absence of declared `x` variable will trigger an error here; to prevent this, use...

```
if (typeof x === 'undefined' || x === null) { ... }
```

But I actually think the true meaning of this warning is that you shouldn't check for both `null` and `undefined` in one branch of code, as these are different values.

Yet if you feel safe about this, you can turn off these particular checks in JSHint, with `eqnull` option. Then...

```
if (x == null) { ... }
```

... will check both for `null` and `undefined`, yet won't trigger the warning. Note, though, that `== undefined` comparisons are not 'covered' by this option.

---

As a sidenote, underscore's `isUndefined` method is an interesting piece of code:

```
_.isUndefined = function(obj) {
  return obj === void 0;
};
```

It's essentially the same as simple `obj === undefined`, yet covers one special case: when someone decided that it's a good idea to overwrite the value of `undefined` in their script. As `void` construct *always* returns "the real `undefined`", this function will work correctly even in this situation.

Comment: That's an interesting way of using `void` :) sure beats my anonymous function wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

The correct replacement is:

```
if( typeof x === "undefined")
```

Comment: Whilst this is correct, I think it would help being fleshed out with an explanation of `==` vs `===` and why you should use `typeof`. Or maybe you're busy typing that just now :o)

Comment: You need to do a typeof to avoid undeclared variables throwing up

Comment: @roryf: `===` and `==` are completely equivalent for this particular case.

Comment: -1 This can break the code. If the original code was written as above, I don't want to debug it now and verify it never accepts null. Right now I just want to refactor it while preserving its original meaning.